# In C, I have an array of char* that I read from a file, when I pass it out of the function by refenrce I get garbage

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, char

I am new to C, I have mostly worked with c++ and c#. Now I am trying to write a function that reads from a file and stores the value in a string, it works within the function but when I try to pass the value out it comes out as nothing or garbage. Is there something I am missing about how C works? Here is an example of what is going wrong.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void getArray(char**);

int main()
{
    char* myArr[2];
    getArray(myArr);
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        printf("%s\n", myArr[i]);
    }
    printf("printing done\n");
    return 0;
}

void getArray(char* arr[])
{
    arr[0] = "poo";

    char str[6];
    FILE* fp;

    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if(fp != NULL)
    {

         fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
         fclose(fp);

    }


    arr[1] = str;
    printf("%s\n", arr[1]);
}
```

that is  the code, and here is the output

```
123456
0
poo
1

printing done
```

and here is the expected output

```
123456
0
poo
1
123456
printing done
```

sorry if  am being redundant I just want to be thorough in my confusion

Comment: `str` is local variable to the function, it stops existing when the function returns

Comment: And `str` is only 6 bytes long. `"123456" requires 7 bytes (1 for the terminating `'\0'`).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you save the contents of the file to a local variable. Local variables will cease to exist after exiting the function.

Explanation:

Inside main you have this:

```
                   addr | var | value
                   ...  
                   0001 | --- | -----
inside main -->    0000 | arr | -----
```

When you enter a function, your local variables are pushed to the stack:

```
                    addr | var | value
                    ...  
inside function --> 0001 | str | -----
                    0000 | arr | -----
```

You read str and points *arr* to the local variable *str*

```
                    addr | var | value
                    ...  
inside function --> 0001 | str | 123456
                    0000 | arr | points to 0001
```

When you leave the function, str will be removed from stack

```
                    addr | var | value
                    ...  
                    0001 | --- | -----
after function  --> 0000 | arr | points to 0001
```

So the variable *str* does not exist anymore, and when you try to do *arr[1]* you are getting garbage.

You can either allocate space for your variable dinamically or load the contents of the file directly to an outside variable, making sure that it will have enough space.

To allocate an array of 6 chars dinamically, use: `char *str = malloc(6 * sizeof(char))` inside your function.

To use an outside variable, simply move `char str[6];` to main, and pass it as parameter to the function:
`void getArray(char* arr[], char* str)`, this way you would be able to change the value of *str* and still keep its value.

Comment: The effort is certainly worth the vote. Good use of visual example.

Comment: Note that a good program will also call `free(str)` (or `free(myArr[0]); free(myArr[1]);`) exactly once when corresponding strings are no longer needed. If it's called twice, you get [undefined behavior](), if it's not called, you get a memory leak. Unlike in other languages, C does not have garbage collection, so it's up to a programmer to explicitly manage strings.

Answer (score 1):

replace `char str[6];` with `char *str = malloc(sizeof(char)*7)`

this way str keeps a place in memory after the function returns

Comment: An important part about `free` is missing. "str keeps a place in memory" --- this is not 100% precise though: `str` is surely out of scope, so it effectively is "destroyed", but the chunk of allocated memory is not.

Comment: Also you should ensure the `fscanf` does not write out of bounds of allocated memory

Comment: @zerkms arr would still have a reference to it though would it not? Would you recommended calling free(myArr[1]) before the program exits?

Comment: It would be a pointer to the allocated memory, but `str` is a local variable. "before the program exits" --- for someone that just learns how to program - certainly.

Comment: so then free(myArr[1]) should prevent any worry about memory leaks

Comment: Yep, it would, I think.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes I did mistype and mean to put 6, thanks! As far as sizeof(char) I always like to add it even if its redundant, it makes it easier to understand what is going on